# Network App Restriction

Tags: applications, sim-card, mobile-network

I recently bought a japanese cellphone (Fujitsu F-06e NX). It came with some really cool apps but most of them have limited functionality due to network work restrictions (Phone must be on docomo ntt network). I was wonder if there was a way to bypass this restriction. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Orbot Proxy by Tor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.torproject.android&hl=en). You will have to root the phone if your apps don't have their own proxy settings. Tor is a very good anonymizing network; in fact, Stack Exchange has their own website for it: [StackExchange](https://tor.stackexchange.com/)

You can also configure a VPN and connect your phone to that, via Settings or by downloading a VPN app. You can subscribe to a private VPN server (small monthly fee), you can create your **own** VPN server, either with OpenVPN software or Windows 7 VPN wizard, or, if privacy doesn't matter, you can connect to a free, public VPN server.

Other than those two methods, options get very difficult from here. There's no reason the above VPN method shouldn't work, unless your device doesn't support it. Still, try a VPN app ([This one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tunnelbear.android&hl=en) seems to be legit and has pretty good reviews).

Sometimes VPN's are blocked as well (think massive corporations), although it is almost impossible to completely block one. Try hosting your own VPN server, in the situation where they have a targeted block-list.

Also, in the event that if your device rejects everything you install on it, one would have to modify the .APK's of the apps themselves to target a custom VPN or proxy server. Programming knowledge is a requirement. This would all be to avoid rooting.

I think that is the entire list. Good luck

Comment: As this is a new phone and I dont have any experience rooting could there be alternative method where I dont have to root?

Comment: Well, Orbot works without root, as long as you can configure proxy settings inside your apps (such as within Firefox mobile, to bypass all websites). I'll update my answer with other methods as well.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but how do one configure that Tor Orbot? I have absolutely no idea how to go about it.